# Trying to access the LauncherProvider

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider

I am trying to access the `LauncherProvider`. You can find its source code [**here**](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher/+/master/src/com/android/launcher/LauncherProvider.java)

I tried to query this `ContentProvider` like this:

```
Uri uri = new Uri.Builder().scheme("content").authority("com.android.launcher.settings").appendPath("favorites").build();
String[] projection = new String[]{
        "_id", "title", "intent", "container", "screen", "cellX", "cellY",
        "spanX", "spanY", "itemType", "appWidgetId", "isShortcut", "iconType",
        "iconPackage", "iconResource", "icon", "uri", "displayMode"
};
String selection = null;
String[] selectionArgs = null;
String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

Cursor query = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
if (query != null) {
    while (query.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d(TAG, query.getString(2));
    }
}
if (query != null) {
    query.close();
}
```

However the `Cursor` I get is always `null`! This is the error I get in the logcat:

```
07-31 15:55:14.703  24773-24773/x.y.z.testE/ActivityThread﹕ Failed to find provider info for com.android.launcher.settings
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Explanation of your problems

You are trying to access the `LauncherProvider`, but that may not be as easy you want. There are two main problems:

1. The LauncherProvider has two permissions:

   - `com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS` to read from it.
   - `com.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS` to write to it.
2. Different OEMs write their own version of the `LauncherProvider` and its authority might be different! On different versions of Android the authority might also be different. For example on my Nexus 5 the authority of the correct provider is `com.android.launcher3.settings`.

Declaring the permissions is of course not a problem, but finding the correct `ContentProvider` can prove difficult, fortunately there is a solution!

---

## Solution

You first have to declare all the required permissions in the manifest like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
```

And after that we need to find the correct provider! You can do that by reading the `PackageInfo` of all the installed apps and looping through all the `ContentProviders` of each app. The `ContentProvider` which has `READ_SETTINGS` and `WRITE_SETTINGS` as read and write permission is the one we are looking for. But we need a more complex logic to find the right one since the permissions are often based on the package name.

```
public static String findLauncherProviderAuthority(Context context) {
    // Gets PackageInfo about all installed apps
    final List<PackageInfo> packs = context.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PROVIDERS);
    if (packs == null) {
        return null;
    }

    for (PackageInfo pack : packs) {
        // This gets the ProviderInfo of every ContentProvider in that app
        final ProviderInfo[] providers = pack.providers;
        if (providers == null) {
            continue;
        }

        // This loops through the ContentProviders
        for (ProviderInfo provider : providers) {

            // And finally we look for the one with the correct permissions
            // We use `startsWith()` and `endsWith()` since only the middle 
            // part might change
            final String readPermission = provider.readPermission;
            final String writePermission = provider.writePermission;
            if(readPermission != null && writePermission != null) {
                final boolean readPermissionMatches = readPermission.startsWith("com.android.") && readPermission.endsWith(".permission.READ_SETTINGS");
                final boolean writePermissionMatches = writePermission.startsWith("com.android.") && writePermission.endsWith(".permission.WRITE_SETTINGS");
                if(readPermissionMatches && writePermissionMatches) {

                    // And if we found the right one we return the authority
                    return provider.authority;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

So this should very reliably return the correct `ContentProvider`! You may want to tweak it a little more if you run into problems on some devices, but on all devices I could test it (and that's a lot of devices) it is working perfectly. You can use the method above like this:

```
final String authority = findLauncherProviderAuthority(getActivity());
final Uri uri = new Uri.Builder().scheme(CONTENT).authority(authority).appendPath(PATH).build();
...
```

I hope I could help you and if you have any further questions please feel free to ask!

Answer (score 0):

For my Nexus 5 device different permissions required

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Above solution doesn't worked, until i changed that.

```
  if(readPermission != null && writePermission != null) {

      final boolean readPermissionMatches = readPermission.startsWith("com.") 
            && readPermission.endsWith(".permission.READ_SETTINGS");
     final boolean writePermissionMatches = writePermission.startsWith("com.") 
            && writePermission.endsWith(".permission.WRITE_SETTINGS");
```