# accessing Launcher database on Lollipop

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, android-5.0-lollipop, android-contentprovider, android-launcher

I am trying to access Launcher database on a Samsung device running Lollipop 5.1.1 following this method [Trying to access the LauncherProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25060064/trying-to-access-the-launcherprovider):  basically, polling PackageManager for installed packages, then iterating through providers to find one with READ_SETTINGS and WRITE_SETTINGS permissions.   In my case *findLauncherProviderAuthority* returns

**com.sec.android.app.launcher.settings**

yet when I use it to build getContentResolver URI and open cursor to access Launcher database favorites table
 I get the

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column;

removing offending column from projection string simply results in similar error with a different column name.
Next I checked on the phone and found an entry in **Settings->App Manager** for TouchWize Home, associated  with permissions

***com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ*** and
***com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE*** .
Figuring this relates to Samsung Launcher, I try using these permissions but now the cursor value comes null.

Any tips and advice greatly appreciated

Comment: actually it helped a lot passing null projection, and I can see the fields array in the debugger; I do see that two of the "usual" fields were dropped and one new one was added, so that explains my SQLite errors.  Now, how should I adjust my code knowing that: just use the minimum common set of fields?  Also, what would be an easy way to dump the table into Logcat screen, by iterating across columns and rows I guess? I don't have sqlite3 on the phone and it's not rooted either, so I guess I need to cobble together some code to dump the table, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would try to pass in a null projection to the content provider, when you get the cursor back, iterate over the columns and grab the names.

```
 if (cursor != null) {
            int columnCount = cursor.getColumnCount();
            for (int i=0; i < columnCount; i++) {
                android.util.Log.e(TAG,"Column [" + i + "]: " + cursor.getColumnName(i));
            }
        }
```

Then you could see what columns the DB has.. Maybe they have columns prefixed.